# Linux kernel driver: what model for NVRAM access?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I just wrote a RTC driver for an NXP RTC chip on my board, it works great.  This chip also has some battery backed RAM that I'd like to make available to a user space application.  The RTC framework doesn't support this.  It's only 512 bytes but I'm tossed between doing a seekable CHAR driver or a full blown BLOCK driver.  I've never done a block driver before but it appears to require a bit more information than a simple CHAR.

I could also interface with IOCTLS but that doesn't feel as clean as it could be.  What feels like the best way to make these bytes available to userland?

[EDIT] I forgot to mention that that the RTC chip is hanging off an I2C port, it's not mapped into memory, thus not making it a good candidate for mmaping. [/EDIT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block drivers are only for devices that look like disk drives. Are you going to put a filesystem on your 512 bytes? No? Make it a character device.

You could just do it like other drivers have. Check out `drivers/char/nvram.c`. That creates a char device you can `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, `lseek()`, and `close()`.

Comment: While your answer came later than the implementation, it was what I ended up doing.  I just implemented a simple char driver with lseek and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think a character device driver implementing `mmap` should be adequate. [Linux Device Drives](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) covers that in chapter 15.

#### Edit:

Well, i2c is a serial bus, so `mmap` is not an option. I will refer you to [Essential Linux Device Drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132396556) book. I believe it has a sample i2c EEPROM char device driver in Chapter 8. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nikolai, the RTC chip is on an I2C bus, without having the NVRAM mapped into memory I don't see how mmap is a likely candidate, but I might be wrong.